# Pass a parameter as list to argo workflow

Tags: yaml, argo-workflows

I have the following JSON file which will be passed as a parameter file to an Argo workflow:

```
{
  "keys": [
    "key1",
    "key2",
    "key3"
  ]
}
```

Accessing "keys" like '{{inputs.parameters.keys}}' reads keys as a string instead of a list.

Is it possible to read an input parameter from a parameter file as a list of values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within an Argo Workflow, parameters are always strings.

You can use [expression templates](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/variables/#expression) to retrieve information from the stringified list.

```yaml
value: '{{=jsonpath(inputs.parameters.keys, "$.0")}}' # get the first item
```